# Can I install drupal 6 and 7 in subfolders of public_html on shared hosting?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

I have a shared hosting account with hostgator, and currently have maybe 6 or 7 drupal 6 sites installed there. Drupal 6 is installed in the public_html folder. I have a couple of Drupal 6 sites running in an multisite arrangement.

I would like to move most of the sites to drupal 7, but one or two cannot because of themes etc.

Can someone point me to a document that lays out how to install d6 and d7 in subfolders of public_html, or explain how it can be done?

If need be I am willing to give up multisite, I was told recently that you can't have both versions of drupal running multisite under public_html...I don't know enough to be sure that this is so, but multisite may be more trouble than it's worth for the few sites I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to run a single multi-site install with both Drupal 6 and 7 sites. (While I have no doubt someone far too clever for their own good could do this as a proof of concept, it would be a horrendous idea to deploy for a live instance.)

You can however create a new vhost for a subfolder of public_html and run your D7 multi-site install there (alternately, move your D6 multi-site to the new subfolder and run D7 from public_html doc root.)

Unless there's more to your setup than you're indicating, it sounds like 2 Drupal installs, 1 D6 and 1 D7, running 'side-by'-side' will do what you want.

Comment: ?Forest Thanks Forest. I am willing to give up multi-site for sure because it's not so hard to get past my skill level with drupal and I don't need extra issues. As far as side by side, individual instances of drupal 6 and 7 on the same shared hosting, you're saying that is fairly easy. Would there be any special needs to set up a site like this:  public_html/d6/myd6site1 -  public_html/d6/myd6site2  - public_html/d7/myd7site1  - public_html/d7/myd7site2

Comment: Weird markdown, none of the listed minimarkdown tags seem to work in comments?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by vhost? Is that something that can be created easily via cpanel? BTW I never meant to create a single site that hosted multi-site d6 and d7; but simply independent d6 and d7 installs that might each support their own multi-site.

Comment: To set up sub-directories for d6 & d7 you may have to check with your hosting provider. Cpanel does allow you to edit vhosts, iirc. Regardless whether you're doing this with cpanel or or your provider is adding them, a vhost is a virtual host that provides Apache with the essential config info for a given domain, incl. its docroot. If all you wanted was 2 multisite installs for d6 and d7 this is a fairly simple set up. Good luck!